# CIDR subnet calculation and python ipcalc

Tags: python, ip-address, cidr

I am questioning the results of the ipcalc module ([ipcalc](http://ipcalc.readthedocs.org)) for Python (it seems that netaddr may be a better choice).

Let's take `192.168.1.25/30` as an example. In binary, the last octet is `00011001 AND 11111100 = 00011000`, so I get `192.168.1.24` as the Network ID and the range `192.168.1.24 - 192.168.1.27`.

Using ipcalc, when I specify

```
subnet = ipcalc.Network('192.168.1.25/30')
for x in subnet: print x
```

The output is

```
192.168.1.25
192.168.1.26
192.168.1.27
192.168.1.28
```

I am not understanding the inconsistency. When using CIDR notation, it seems that specifying both `192.168.1.24/30` and `192.168.1.25/30` (or `.26/30` or `.27/30`) refer to the same subnet.

Is that correct? Is this just a bug in the ipcalc module?

Comment: FWIW, [Python netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_01.html) is packaged by Fedora, while ipcalc isn't. Also, it's better documented and its Github repository was updated more recently. Last but not least it follows the CIDR definition for your example, e.g. `netaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.1.25/30') == netaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.1.24/30')` evaluates to `True` and `list(netaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.1.25/30'))` prints addresses '192.168.1.24' to '192.168.1.27'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug for this at the moment: [No way to resolve IP + Netmask to Network Object](https://github.com/tehmaze/ipcalc/issues/18)

And an earlier bug report that discuss the matter: [Strange subnet calculations](https://github.com/tehmaze/ipcalc/issues/4)

---

But they have also added a function called `network` to get the network address from an IP. From the manual:

```
>>> localnet = Network('127.128.99.3/8')
>>> print localnet.network()
127.0.0.0
```

The manual specifically says that the constructor `Network` should take a *network address* as its first argument, not any IP in the network. Rather confusing if you ask me (especially since the above code block breaks that condition). I would at least read the code for the module before using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct the subnet is 192.168.1.24/30 so the ips 192.168.1.24 to 192.168.1.27 make part of this network.

Comment: Hm, but '192.168.1.25/30' isn't incorrect either and describes the same IP range, right? So ipcalc is incorrect.